# Best way to move data with overlap towards the end on same device

Tags: filesystems, partition, dd

I have a rather big disk that's pretty full. I need a new partition at the start of this disk. So I need to move the data towards the back of the disk somehow.

Usually I do such things with `dd`, but this is a lot of data, and I have nowhere to store the whole blob in the meantime. And merely using `dd` on overlapping areas doesn't work out too well.

One way seems to be:

1. `resize2fs` the filesystem to minimum size, freeing N bytes at the end.
2. `dd` the last uncopied N bytes to after the uncopied boundary until start of filesystem is reached.
3. Remove partition, and make new at old offset + N bytes with same end sector.
4. `resize2fs` the filesystem to maximum size.

Are there any easier ways to do this? Existing tools, maybe?

Comment: Considering the development effort it would take to create such a tool in a reliable manner... it's just so much cheaper to buy a new disk. What about just buying a bigger disk, creating the new partition on it and then using `partclone` to migrate the old partition to the new disk? Then you can just use the "old" disk for sneaker-ware. Heck, with LVM you can take advantage of both disks and get even more storage space.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/347029/reading-from-the-end-of-a-drive-with-dd

Comment: Do you have to move anything? Partitions don't have to be in number order.

Comment: @meuh I want to put an EFI partition on the disk. Has to be on the first 2 TB, AFAIK.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think GParted can't do this? I know it can move a partition backwards, which is only slightly harder. (It invoked another tool to do the heavy lifting, and it was more specific than `dd`, but I don't remember the exact executable name.)